# Why download from Ethereum Swarm too low?

Tags: swarm

I have two 100mbps servers.

On server #1 I execute: `swarm up 50mb.testfile`

On server #2 I execute: `wget -O 50mb.testfile http://localhost:8500/bzz:/.../`

I see download speed 70KB/s

In swarm log I see

> WARN [10-28|12:09:46.765] ChunkStore.Get can not retrieve chunk
>   err="context deadline exceeded"

Why download speed so low?